# JSON formatting for Terraform API

Tags: json, terraform

I am trying to create a JSON file that will add env variables to a TFE workspace via API.. I am new to JSON so bear with me.. below is what I am trying to use but I can’t seem to get the brackets or formatting correct.. can someone help me out?

```
{
  "data": {
    "type":"vars",
    "attributes": {
      "key":"ID1",
      "value":"xxxxxx",
      "description":"",
      "category":"terraform",
      "hcl":false,
      "sensitive":false
    }
  }
  
  "data": {
    "type":"vars",
    "attributes": {
      "key":"ID2",
      "value":"xxxxxx",
      "description":"",
      "category":"terraform",
      "hcl":false,
      "sensitive":false
    }
  }
  
  "data": {
    "type":"vars",
    "attributes": {
      "key":"ID3",
      "value":"xxxxxx",
      "description":"",
      "category":"terraform",
      "hcl":false,
      "sensitive":true
    }
  }
  
  "data": {
    "type":"vars",
    "attributes": {
      "key":"ID4",
      "value":"xxxxxx",
      "description":"",
      "category":"terraform",
      "hcl":false,
      "sensitive":true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is invalid json. Sorry, its not clear what do you want to do, and what it has to do with terraform?

Comment: I am trying to create variables using TFE API.. example below. Adding one works, but I am trying to format the JSON to add several at a time

https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/api/variables.html#create-a-variable

Comment: It might be worth bearing in mind that https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/api/variables.html#create-a-variable has been deprecated in favour of https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/api/workspace-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

The following is a valid JSON payload:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "vars",
      "attributes": {
        "key": "ID1",
        "value": "xxxxxx",
        "description": "",
        "category": "terraform",
        "hcl": false,
        "sensitive": false
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "vars",
      "attributes": {
        "key": "ID2",
        "value": "xxxxxx",
        "description": "",
        "category": "terraform",
        "hcl": false,
        "sensitive": false
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "vars",
      "attributes": {
        "key": "ID3",
        "value": "xxxxxx",
        "description": "",
        "category": "terraform",
        "hcl": false,
        "sensitive": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "vars",
      "attributes": {
        "key": "ID4",
        "value": "xxxxxx",
        "description": "",
        "category": "terraform",
        "hcl": false,
        "sensitive": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```